# how to save the threshold from H2O model_performance function in Python?

Tags: python, h2o

I am running H2O in Python and build GBM model for binary target variable (1 vs 0). The model perform well and I can see the threshold in the output. But I want to save the threshold to a variable (we can call it cut_point). So when I score a new data set, I can use the threshold to define either 1 or 0. Has anyone has done this before?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [find_threshold_by_max_metric](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html?#h2o.model.binomial.H2OBinomialModel.find_threshold_by_max_metric)

```
model.find_threshold_by_max_metric('f1', train=True, valid=False, xval=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! When I apply model_performance on test data set, from the output I do see the threshold. Is there a way to find the threshold using the test data set?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, for finding [thresholds that maximize F1-scores](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html#f1), one can use:

```
model.F1(train=True, valid=True, xval=False)
```

The sample output of the line above:

> {u'train': [[0.3869697386893616, 0.7451099672437997]], u'valid':
> [[0.35417599264806404, 0.7228980805623143]]}

The threshold value that maximizes the F1-score for each data set is the first value (index 0) of the list in each key. The second value (index 1) is the maximum of F1-score for each data set. To index a threshold value of, say the validity frame one can use:

```
values = model.F1(train=True, valid=True, xval=False)
values.get('valid')[0]
```

This method also works for the following metrics:

- [Gini Coefficient](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html#gini-coefficient)
- [Absolute MCC (Matthews Correlation Coefficient)](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html#absolute-mcc-matthews-correlation-coefficient)
- [F0.5](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html#f0-5)
- [F2](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html#f2)
- [Accuracy](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html#accuracy)